# Adding a marker using a controller to a Google Maps initialised in a directive

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, controller, directive

I have a Google Maps with options instantiated inside a directive :

```
.directive('uiMap',
    ['uiMapConfig', '$parse', function (uiMapConfig, $parse) {

        var mapEvents = 'bounds_changed center_changed click dblclick drag dragend ' +
            'dragstart heading_changed idle maptypeid_changed mousemove mouseout ' +
            'mouseover projection_changed resize rightclick tilesloaded tilt_changed ' +
            'zoom_changed';
        var options = uiMapConfig || {};

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            //doesn't work as E for unknown reason
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
                var opts = angular.extend({}, options, scope.$eval(attrs.uiOptions));
                var map = new window.google.maps.Map(elm[0], opts);
                var model = $parse(attrs.uiMap);

                //Set scope variable for the map
                model.assign(scope, map);

                bindMapEvents(scope, mapEvents, map, elm);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

The map is displayed correctly thanks to this div :

```
<section id="map">
    <div ui-map="myMap" ui-options="ctrl.mapOptions" class="google-map"></div>
</section>
```

What I am trying to do is to add a marker on this map after clicking on a button using a controller:

```
this.findAddress = function() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        title:"Hello World!"
    });

    marker.setMap(map);

}
```

The problem is that the "map" is undefined in the controller and I don't know how to access to the instance of the map.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `uiMap` directive you could notify the controller once the map is created  via [`$emit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit):

```
 scope.$emit('mapReady', map);
```

In controller

```
$scope.map = null;
$scope.$on('mapReady', function (event, map) {
    $scope.map = map; 
});
```

and

```
 $scope.findAddress = function () {
      //create a marker here...      
      marker.setMap($scope.map);
 }
```

Example

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('uiMap',
    ['$parse', function ($parse) {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
                var opts = scope.$eval(attrs.uiOptions);
                var map = new window.google.maps.Map(elm[0], opts);
                scope.$emit('mapReady', map);
            }
        };
    }])
    .controller('MapCtrl', [
        '$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.map = null;
            $scope.mapOptions = {
                zoom: 12,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.870501, 151.206704),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            };

            $scope.isMapReady = function(){
                return $scope.map != null;
            }


            $scope.$on('mapReady', function (event, map) {
                $scope.map = map; 
            });


            $scope.findAddress = function () {
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.870501, 151.206704);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    title: "Hello World!"
                });
                marker.setMap($scope.map);
            }


        }]);
```

```css
.google-map {
            width: 640px;
            height: 320px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>



  <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="MapCtrl">
           
            <button ng-click="findAddress()"  ng-disabled="!isMapReady()">Find address</button>
            <section id="map">
                <div ui-map="myMap" ui-options="{{mapOptions}}" class="google-map"></div>
            </section>

        </div>
</div>
```